# Excel 2010: Vlookup Name from one column & Count and return data from another column

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif, formulas

Hoping someone can help me here. :)

---

**I have two columns of data in Worksheet 1:**

```
COLUMN A = NAME (EG. TOM)

COLUMN C = TYPE OF QUERY (FAX, TEL, EMAIL, MAIL)
```

---

**I would like to have in Worksheet 2:**

```
COLUMN A = NAME (EG TOM)

COLUMN B = A COUNT OF HOW MANY FAXES TOM HAS

COLUNN C = A COUNT OF HOW MANY TELEPHONES TOM HAS

COLUMN D - A COUNT OF HOW MANY EMAILS TOM HAS

COLUMN E = A COUNT OF HOW MANY MAILS TOM HAS
```

---

If anyone can help me that would be great.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table. In sheet 1, click into the data table, then click Insert > Pivot table.

Drag the Name field to the rows. Drag the query type field to the columns. 
Drag the Namie field again, this time to the Values area, where it will turn into a count.

Now you see a count of query types for each name in a matrix.

Comment: Both you guys rock, thanks, I have worked it out with a Pivot. Thanks a heap!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `countifs` instead if you really want to use formula. A pivot table would be the best way to go though.
eg for column B, row 1 on sheet 2:
`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A, A1, Sheet1!C:C, "FAX")`